# Playframework with Deadbolt 2: Pattern regular expression not match

Tags: regex, scala, playframework-2.3, deadbolt-2

I am using `Deadbolt2` with `play-framework 2.3.x`. When I am trying to access the controller with declare deadbolt `Patterns` using regular expressions. I am getting `Not-found` error. [According to this sample](http://deadbolt-2-scala.herokuapp.com/#controller-Pattern), it is possible to use regular expressions with `Pattern` in our application. But when I declare a regular expression, I am not able to use it. My code looks like this:

```
def pattern_one = Pattern("CH{4,}", PatternType.REGEX, new MyDeadboltHandler) {} // NOT ACCESSED 

def pattern_one = Pattern("CH*", PatternType.REGEX, new MyDeadboltHandler) {  // NOT ACCESSED

def pattern_one = Pattern("CHANNEL", PatternType.REGEX, new MyDeadboltHandler) { // ACCESSED SUCCESSFULLY
```

Comment: Do you mean a pattern like `CH.{4,}` or `CH.*`? (Note the extra `.` in my expression.) Why do you want to match something like `CHHHHHHH`? Are you working on a chemical application?

Comment: Could it be the  missing `.` in the regular expressions `CH.{4,}` and `CH.*`?

Comment: @GáborBakos its just create for sample application, for testing how regular expressions are work with `deadbolt`.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara I am pretty sure they work similarly to other programs. What I tried to express: It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @GregorRaýman this is work for me. My `CH.*` and `CH.{4,}` runs successfully. But still i am not getting, why we need `.` for regular expressions ?

Comment: Deadbolt compiles regexs using the standard Java library: `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(patternValue)`. See https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/DeadboltActions.scala#L117-L122 and https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/DeadboltActions.scala#L137 for implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions are not wildcards. If a `*` wildcard matches anything any number of times, in regex, you need to use `.*`, where `.` means *any character but a newline*, and `*` means *0 or more times*.

More, if you want to match the whole string that contains a word in a string starting with `CH`, you can use a word boundary, `\\b`: `\\bCH.*`.

If you want to specify that the string must start with `CH` and match the whole string, you can use `^CH.*`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `CH.*` or `CH.{4,}` if you want something (not just `H`s) after `CH`. The `.` means any character, just like in any other regular expression.

Comment: this answer was already given by @ Gregor Raýman in above comments

Comment: This answer was already given by me in the above comments: " `CH.{4,}` or `CH.*`? (Note the extra `.` in my expression.) " before him. ;) (And this is a bit more detailed.)

Comment: sorry @Gábor Bakos its my mistake